# How do I add JSON objects from two functions into a function?

Tags: javascript

I want to add the two objects together from the first two function and return the added objects together in a another function. Now how do I do that?

```
function firstfunc(){
   var object1 = {
   //Relevant code
   };
}

function secondfunc(){
   var object2 = {
   //Relevant code
   };
}

function thirdfunc(){
   var total = Object.assign(object1, object2);
   return total;    
}
```

Comment: **Unrelated:** There is nothing called JSON code in JS, rather, there is something called JSON string.

Comment: What does "add" mean? Also, what do your objects look like?

Comment: I want to copy the values of the first object and the second object and put those values into a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the objects in the first 2 functions and call those functions within the third

```js
function firstfunc(){
   var o = {
     foo:'bar'
   };
   return o;
}

function secondfunc(){
   var o = {
     bar:'foo'
   };
   return o;
}

function thirdfunc(){
   var total = Object.assign({}, firstfunc(), secondfunc());
   return total;    
}

console.log(thirdfunc())
```

Comment: `Object.assign(...firstfunc(), ...secondfunc());` would be a less verbose way to do this, correct?

Comment: @23k less characters actually the way I wrote it so don't see why it is less verbose. Rather it is an alternative way to write it assuming OP is supporting ES6

Comment: easier to read in my opinion. Though it is just an opinion :)

Comment: The first argument to assign is the target, so it expects to modify that argument.  It works, but I like to remind myself that that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, object1 and object2 are scoped to firstfunc and secondfunc, so not accessiable to thirdfunc.  Are you wanting to merge the results of firstfunc and secondfunc together?  That would look something like this:

```
function firstfunc() {
    return {
        // object 1 data
    };
}

function secondfunc() {
    return {
        // object 2 data
    };
}

function thirdfunc(){
    return Object.assign({}, firstfunc(), secondfunc());
}
```